# How to ignore certain endpoints using Spring Security Oauth

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring security, oauth in the following way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .jdbc(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());

  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

    configurer.tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .reuseRefreshTokens(true)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

  }

}
```

I want to now make certain URL's public, so that no token is required to access those resources.  For example `/public/**`

How would I do this?  Do I need to use a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?  Thanks for any help!

***UPDATE***

I added the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as pointed out below. So now the `/public/**` URL is accessible without any tokens.  However, all other endpoints are no longer accessible, and respond with `403 Forbidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For making the path `public/**` open without authentication, you can configure the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected.  Yes, the public URL is now accessible.  However, the other URL's (for which I am sending oauth token in `Authorization` header, and was working before) now respond with 403 Forbidden.

Comment: what does the log say when you get 403? Can you try here to set Spring Security log level to DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

you should have something like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login*").permitAll();

}
```